# having a hard time getting the width of an Li parent element, child cannot inherit width?

Tags: css, reactjs

Screenshot:

[image]

I currently have this code:

```
<li
  style={{
   border: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
   width: '100%',
  }}
  key={uuidV4()}
>
 <span style={{ width: 'inherit' }}> // setting it to 100% or inherit, dont change anything
   <span style={{ width: '90%' }}>{`${toTitleCase(column)} `}</span>
     <span style={{ width: '10%' }}>
       <Button
         style={{
          width: '25px',
          fontSize: '18px',
          padding: '0',
          borderRadius: '50%',
         }}
         color="link"
         onClick={e => this.addActiveColumn(e, column)}
       >
        <i
          style={{
           borderRadius: '50%',
           backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
           color: '#343A40',
          }}
          className="fa fa-plus-circle"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
       </Button>
      </span>
     </span>
    </li>
```

I wanted the text to have 90% width of the li element, then the + button to have 10% so the + button will be on the rightest side properly aligned, but the result is not what I am expecting. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` is an inline element by default, to which the `width` property doesn't affect. You can change it to `display: inline-block` or `display: block'`

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jackyef/pen/dJrGWW) to see what I mean

Comment: Thanks! i didn't know it's not affecting.